# Почему в редакторе всё работает, а на лит коде нет

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, ооп, list

У меня есть вопросик решал литкод задачи на массивы (88. Merge Sorted Array) в редакторе vs code всё работает нормально, а на самом сайте не сортирует массив. Версия Python 3.11.7
Вот мой код:

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        nums1 = nums1[:m]
        nums2 = nums2[:n]
        res = nums1 + nums2
        res.sort()
        return res


s = Solution()

print(s.merge([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], 3, [2, 5, 6], 3))
```

На литкод тоже что и здесь, но без создания объекта и вывода результата функции.

Comment: p.s return тоже с табом.

Comment: Докстринг из задачи `Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.`

Comment: @MaksimAlekseev, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что есть такого рода задачи.

Answer (score 2):

В этой задаче необходимо эффективно использовать память и не создавать новые объекты в памяти.

В задаче в докстринг-е, как раз это указано:

```py
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """
```

`Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.` - Не возвращайте ничего, вместо этого измените nums1 на месте.

---

Возможное решение:

```py
i = m - 1
j = n - 1
last = m + n - 1
while j >= 0:
    if i >= 0 and nums1[i] > nums2[j]:
        nums1[last] = nums1[i]
        last -= 1
        i -= 1
    else:
        nums1[last] = nums2[j]
        last -= 1
        j -= 1
```

- Создаем указатели на элементы массива `i` и `j`
- И указатель на последний элемент `last`
- Идем с конца и заполняем главный массив `nums1`
  до тех пор пока не дойдем до первого элемента второго массива.
- при каждой итерации уменьшаем указатели

[88. Merge Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/description/)